# How do I tell which sublime plugin(s) are resource hogs?

Tags: plugins, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, resources

Just what the title says, the rest is detail :)

Relatively often my ST3 instance hangs for a couple of seconds (or just now, which prompted this post, it hung indefinitely and I had to kill the `plugin_host` process).  It doesn't seem to have a specific relation to anything logical like file size or type, so I'm (generally) ruling out things like linters.

Rather than disabling each plugin one by one, working for a while, seeing if it happens for a day (it might happen 2-3 times an hour, or once/day, it's fairly random), I'm hoping someone might have advice on how to figure out which plugin is the culprit?

On OSX, in case there is a relevant solution involving some OS-level resource monitoring.